# jquery date value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] when saving to dajngo?

Tags: jquery, django, date, time

my jquery code goes like ...

```
$("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
      selectedFrom = $(this).val();
      fromDateInput.value = selectedFrom;
  });

function ajax_call(data){

    data = { 
    'from_input' : fromDateInput.value }
}
```

my model is ...

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    res_from = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

then my view goes like ...

```
def reservationview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from_input = request.POST.get('from_input')
        Reservation.objects.create(res_from = from_input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view doesn't know how to recognize the input.  There is a utility in `dateutil` that can help you convert most date/time formats to a datetime.

```
from dateutil import parser

def reservationview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from_input = parser.parse(request.POST.get('from_input'))
        Reservation.objects.create(res_from = from_input)
```